# Indexing Service filter daemon keeps crashing on Windows XP; something worse underneath?

Tags: windows-xp, services

The Indexing Service filter daemon keeps crashing on my Windows XP Pro machine, with the following error message:

```
Indexing Service filter daemon has encountered a problem and needs to close.  
We are sorry for the inconvenience.
```

Not a big deal, I can click "Don't Send Error Report" all day.  But what's going on, here?  Is this a service that I need?  Is the frequent crashing indicative of something worse that's happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open **My Computer**
2. Right click your hard drive icon and select **properties**.
3. At the bottom of the window you'll see **Allow indexing service to index this disk for faster searches**, uncheck this and click **Ok**.
4. A new window will pop up and select **Apply** to all folders and subfolders. It will take a a minute or two for the changes to take affect but then you should enjoy slightly faster performance